# Unable to create a list in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am doing this for my Java class. We learned about linked list and did some practices on it. However, I am still unable to write a code that works. For this one, the problem is that my tester shows that my code does not work. I created a new list, but I was unable to navigate through it and unable to add a node to it.

```
public class GenDoubleLinkedList <T> {
    private class ListNode
    {
        private T data;
        private ListNode link;

        public ListNode()
        {
            data = null;
            link = null;
        }
        public ListNode(T aData, ListNode aLink)
        {
            data = aData;
            link = aLink;
        }
    }

    private ListNode head;
    private ListNode curr;
    private ListNode prev;

    public GenDoubleLinkedList()
    {
        head = new ListNode();
        curr = head;
    }


    public void goToNext() {
        if (curr != null)
        {
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.link;
        }
    }

    public void goToPrev()
    {
        if(curr != head)
        {
        curr = prev;
        prev = head;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("current is head");
        }
    }

    public T getDataAtCurrent()
    {
        if(curr != null)
        {
            return curr.data;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setDataAtCurrent(T aData)
    {
        if (curr != null)
        {
            curr.data = aData;
        }
    }

    public void insertNodeAfterCurrent(T aData)
    {
        ListNode newNode = new ListNode(aData, null);
        if(curr != null)
        {
            newNode.link = curr.link;
        }
        else if(head == null)
        {
                System.out.println("current is outside of the list");
        }
        else
        {
                System.out.println("The list is empty");
        }   

    }

    public void deleteCurrentNode()
    {
        if(curr != null && prev != null)
        {
            prev.link = curr.link;
            curr = curr.link;
        }
        else if(curr != null && prev == null)
        {
            head = head.link;
            curr = head;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Cannot delete something that does not exist.");
        }
    }

    public void showList()
    {
        ListNode temp = head;
        while(temp != null)
        {

                System.out.println(temp.data);
                temp = temp.link;
        }

    }

    private boolean inList(T aData)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        ListNode position = head;
        while(position != null && !found)
        {
            T dataAtPosition = position.data;
            if(dataAtPosition.equals(aData))
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
                found = false;
        }
        return found;

    }
}
```

Comment: what is the output of your 'tester' and what is the expected output?

Comment: TL;DR; Is all this code needed to demonstrate the issue ? See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Your `insertNodeAfterCurrent()` is implemented wrongly.

```
public void insertNodeAfterCurrent(T aData)
{
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(aData, null);

    if(curr != null)
    {
        // The original is wrong.
        // newNode.link = curr.link; 
        curr.link = newNode;
        goToNext();
    }
    else if(head == null)
    {
            System.out.println("current is outside of the list");
    }
    else
    {
            System.out.println("The list is empty");
    }   
}
```

Just a side note, your `goToPrev()` is wrong too. The main reason is your "double linked list" is singly linked. If you are not going to make it really doubly linked, then you have to iterate for `goToPrev()`, which is another O(n) operation.

```
public void goToPrev()
{
    if(curr != head)
    {
        curr = prev;

        prev = head;
        while (prev.link != curr) prev = prev.link;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("current is head");
    }
}
```